# JPA Specification sort by native SQL field

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I'm using Spring Boot v1.5.3
In my code, I have a search operation with a lot of conditions.

```
public Page<ParentObject> search(Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<ParentObject> specification = (root, cq, cb) -> {
        Predicate p = cb.and(
            cb.equals(root.get("child").get("id"), "someValue"),
            // a lot of predicates appended by conditions
            );
        return p;
    };
    Sort newSort = pageable.getSort().and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "child.id"));
    pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), newSort)
    Page<ParentObject> result = parentObjectRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
    return result;
}
```

The problem is that my `parent` table contains `child_id` field with index. And I want SQL to be like:

```
SELECT .... FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON c.id = p.child_id WHERE ... 
ORDER BY p.child_id ASC;
```

But in result I have:

```
SELECT .... FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON c.id = p.child_id WHERE ... 
ORDER BY c.id ASC;
```

Pay attention to `ORDER BY` clause. If I have `c.id` index is not involved and the search is slow. If I have `ORDER BY p.child_id` it works much faster.
I tried to use

```
Sort newSort = pageable.getSort().and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "child"));
```

but it does not work as expected.
Entity:

```
public class ParentObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ChildObject child;
}
```

I can't replace this by native SQL, because this search specification contains 30+ if/else statements and it will take a lot of time to rewrite the code.

How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: use this instead: Sort newSort = pageable.getSort().and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "child.id"));

Comment: @Lemmy as you see from the code from my question - it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution. As we know, ORM works with database thru entities.
All my entities have String (UUID) values as ids. So, I have added the following code into my ParentObject:

```
public class ParentObject {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private ChildObject child;

    @Column(name = "child_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String childId;
}
```

As you see, here I have added simple field that contains id of child object. It's important to mark this field as `insertable = false, updatable = false` and we can't change this field in the code, this is read-only field. But this allows us to sort results by `parent.child_id`, not by `child.id`. If we need to replace child object, need just call `setChild(newValue)`.

And finally, my search method now looks like:

```
public Page<ParentObject> search(Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<ParentObject> specification = (root, cq, cb) -> {
        Predicate p = cb.and(
            cb.equals(root.get("child").get("id"), "someValue"),
            // a lot of predicates appended by conditions
            );
        return p;
    };
     // IMPORTANT change in next line
    Sort newSort = pageable.getSort().and(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "childId"));
    pageable = new PageRequest(pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize(), newSort)
    Page<ParentObject> result = parentObjectRepository.findAll(specification, pageable);
    return result;
}
```

And in result I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT .... FROM parent p INNER JOIN child c ON c.id = p.child_id WHERE ... 
ORDER BY p.child_id ASC;
```

Hope this would be useful for someone